# Change user password in AWS Babelfish

Tags: t-sql, amazon-rds, psql, amazon-aurora, babelfish

I'm trying to change the password of a Babelfish login. In a psql session, I tried the following command:

```
alter role <username> set password = '<newpassword>'
```

But I get the error

```
ERROR:  Babelfish-created logins/users/roles cannot be altered outside of a Babelfish session
```

So I tried changing it with TSQL in a Babelfish session, logged in as `<my_user>`, with this command:

```
alter login <username> with password = '<newpassword>'
```

and I get this error:

```
Msg 33557097, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
must be member of "rds_superuser" to alter members of "rds_superuser"
```

And when I run this in psql

```
GRANT rds_superuser TO <my_user>;
```

I get this:

```
**NOTICE:  role "<my_user>" is already a member of role "rds_superuser"
```

I feel like I'm missing something obvious. Help!